# how to install Ubuntu on a fresh hard drive

Tags: installation, hard-drive

I attempted to install Ubuntu from a USB stick to my Intel 4 3GHz computer with 80GB HDD.
The installer was doing well, then it said something to the effect of "errors on the source USB, or the target HDD"  The recommendation was to download the installer again.
I suspected my HDD was going bad so I figured I would investigate.

What I found was a partially formatted 80GB HDD. I repartitioned it via a different computer.
Now a fresh copy of the Ubuntu USB installer is not able to move past the start-up screen (it freezes).

I was able to purchase a new / clean HDD, but still the fresh copy of the installer still locks up after the initial opening screen (locks up after about 2 screens worth of installations steps).

Does this sounds like a HDD NTHS issue or a CPU/hardware/memory issue?

or should I move to a CD image file rather than my USB stick?

Now my computer is stuck... no OS.. no way to go back to Windows (upgrade OS CD only).

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Stuck in Schenectady
Herman Wiegman

Answer (score 0):

In this case perhaps you should create a LiveCD (since you're being told your USB stick might have a problem).

Boot from the CD (or DVD, whatever you created) and choose "Try Ubuntu" when given that option.  You'll end up with an Ubuntu desktop, and if you open the Dash (top button on the Unity taskbar) and then start typing "gparted" (it'll probably show the icon for it before you've typed more than "gp..."), click on the icon, and GParted will open.  With it you can work with partitions: create, delete, resize, move, format, etc.

It'll be interesting to see what partitions there are on your HDD, if it's just one or if there is something else there.  Let us know what GParted shows.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, I helped someone to install ubuntu on a dual boot system. The link is: [installation of ubuntu 12.04 starting but not getting completed](https://askubuntu.com/q/148964/23725) See if its helpful for you. The comments in the answer might be helpful for you too.