# installation of ubuntu 12.04 starting but not getting completed

Tags: system-installation

I have burnt the iso image on a CD.I am able to boot from the CD.I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside windows.everything was working fine.resizing the partitions was done,installation started....it showed various features ubuntu has then it started retrieving files.while retrieving suddenly screen went blank.i tried 2-3 times but the same thing is happening again and again.i spent my whole day but not getting the solution
:(.somebody please help me...I also checked whether iso file is proper using Winmd5sum.it shows same values on comparing hashes.please help....

Comment: Please somebody help.....It's urgent!!can somebody guess what might be the problem?Everything is working fine and suddenly the system shuts down.Windows XP is working fine.since i did 2-3 times resizing the partitions was done many times.can this be  a problem???I will be extremely thankful if someone can guide me installing through the CD.waiting eagerly for reply!!Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest:

1. Try installing the system once again but don't select to download updates during installation. You can do that later too. If this does not help:
2. As md5 hashes of iso are correct, I don't see anything else except burning the iso image again ( on another cd or pen drive, if you have one) and try installing then.

See if it helps.

Comment: Thanks drake01  i'l try again but while installing it asks to unmount partition.is it ok if i unmount partitions again n again whenever i try to install?

Comment: Yeah, mounting and unmounting the partitions are a normal practice in linux. Its just like letting linux select a drive. Like you'd have mounted a pen drive and unmounted (safely removed) it in other operating system windows/mac.

Comment: should i use gparted to partition my windows first or is it ok if i dont do that coz i already have 20gb free space in my d drive

Comment: Assuming that you have only one operating system i.e. windows and you want to install the ubuntu on a dedicated partition ( d drive in this case), It depends on your needs. After you have installed ubuntu, it takes around 4 GB of the hard disk space. You are then left with 14 GB for your personal use. If you are a casual user who'd anyways install a new linux distro in say 6 months or reinstall if need more space, 20 GBs should be good enough. You can keep the heavy multimedia files (movies), iso images to other partitions as you'd be able to access windows partition too from ubuntu.

Comment: Also use gparted with care. If you try to contract windows partition with it, it may hurt it if not used carefully. You may try windows partition manager or some freeware for windows ( easeus partition manager) for windows. After you have decided which partition to be used for ubuntu installtion, boot the live cd/pendrive -> In the partition table select the partition that you want to have ubuntu upon -> format it ( be careful here, you'd lose precious data if you selected any other partition) Set it as / and decide the file journalling system (ext3/ext4). Allocate swap n follow instructions.

Comment: Thanks drake one more thing i wanted to ask u that will ubuntu automatically install in free partition of d drive coz i have free space in c drive also.actually while installing in ubuntu i cant see c or d drive,i can only see sda,sdb....n ya while installing it tells me to slide the partition.how should i slide it?

Comment: how do i come to know about my free partition from partition table?as i told u it does not show C or D drive.it shows something which i dont understand and what is swapping and ext3 all about?sorry but i am new to ubuntu.thanks in advance:)

Comment: It seems its your first attempt at installation of ubuntu. So to avoid damage, I suggest: Don't try to shrink or expand the partitions. You seem to have d drive of 20GB. Empty it by moving the contents to other drives. I hope you don't have any drive of 20 GB except this one. (If you have any drive of 20 GB, I assume there would be some big files and having less space than 20 GB say they have 14 GB or 15GB but not 20 GB) This will help you decide which is D drive in the partition table.

Comment: If the d drive is empty It should show almost same space in the fields: total space and space available and it'd have very less used space say few MBs. Be careful to decide the correct partition in the partition table. Its the most crucial step of installtion.

Comment: ok thank u so much drake01.i'l give it a try and let u know:)

Comment: These are the various partitions i get to choose from sda1(ntfs)-32.5GB, sda5(ntfs)-43.9GB, sda10(ext4)-9.6GB, sda6(ntfs)-41.2GB, sda9(ext4)-10.9GB, sda7(ext4)-20.9GB,sda8(linux-swap)-1.1GB.out of these sda5 has minimum used space i.e. 3235MB.should i select it as device for boot loader installation?when i select it i get error:"No root file system is defined.plz correct this from the partitioning menu"..plz reply fast

Comment: I really can't tell for sure the exact things, but a few hints should help you. Were you able to see the drive on which you want to install ubuntu in windows? If yes, that was not ext4 partition and you should choose from ntfs. Among them if you have that d drive empty, it should show here also with minimum used space which I don't know. As the partitions are of considerable different sizes, you should know which was the d drive, I can't help here.

Comment: Now the bootloader thing: You should have the first option in the drop down list as sda with description of the hard disk manufacturer. This should be the very first option in drop down. You should select that. It is not your linux filesystem location. Its about bootloader. Thats different from the system installtion partition.

Comment: thanks drake:)then where do i select the partition where i want to install ubuntu?

Comment: i mean my D drive.shud i choose the tab change??

Comment: Just above that bootloader thing, you should see a table with details of the partitions on your system. Select the correct partition (select carefully here). Double click on that-> set the filesystem (ext4) , set as / (i.e. root), check the format option -> click ok, select bootloader as mentioned in previous comment. Continue. (Be Careful, once you format the partition you'd lose the partition's previous data if any). After this everything should be trivial.

Comment: Thanks that worked:)but now after filling username and all m getting "there were no suitable operating systems to import from"while i shud get a choice to  import from windows right?shud i continue?will it affect my windows?

Comment: Nah, its ok to have no user to import from. Its actually checking whether you have any pre-existing linux distro (another ubuntu) that has accounts you would like to keep settings of. Its ok, at the end, the installer should be able to detect windows.

Comment: Thanks a lot drake01!!:D Finally my ubuntu installation is complete  and that too on the correct partition.Credit goes to u.Thanks a lot....:)

Comment: Welcome to the world of Linux. Hope that your experience with linux and unlimited learning opportunities provided by it be happier one.. :-)